# Jenkins log4j Dependency / Version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am wrapping a third-party library that uses log4j, in order to provide a `Builder` implementation to invoke the functions of this library as a build step.

The third-party library directly depends on log4j, and is using the usual logging mechanism. This includes `trace()` logging.

However, Jenkins seems to be depending on some legacy version of log4j, which does not contain the `trace()` method. As a result I am getting `NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/Object;)V`.

I have added a dependency to the latest version of log4j in my `hpi` project's POM. However, this has made no difference.

How can I make a later version of log4j available to my plugin?